# Unable to install tesserocr on Mac

Tags: python, django, macos, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to install tesserocr with the command:

```
pip install tesserocr
```

but I'm getting this error:

> ```
> tesserocr.cpp:298:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found
>
>     #include <utility>
>              ^~~~~~~~~
>     1 warning and 1 error generated.
>     error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
> ```

I have installed tesseract using: `brew install tesseract`

I'm using Mojave 10.14.3.

Comment: try running `brew install tesseract` and then `pip install tesserocr`

Comment: Thanks but it dint' help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `CC=clang XCC=clang++ CPPFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE -mmacosx-version-min=10.8" pip install tesserocr`. It works fine for me.

And this original answer is from https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/177.

Good Luck!